# Good netbook OS

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

What is The best Linux netbook OS.

Comment: This question is too board and answers are likely to be based on opinions rather than facts. I also noticed the original post in the [revision history](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/620307/1) which could be classed as borderline spam and would almost definitely have been flagged as such. Just be more careful in future in the way you mention software whether it be open source or otherwise.

Comment: This question has multiple problems which make it unsuitable here: first, it's not about Ubuntu specifically.  This site is only for Ubuntu related questions, not other OSes.  Second, it's too opinion-based.  Questions need to have clear answers, not just solicit people's subjective opinions.  Third, it's too broad.  It doesn't specify enough information for people to know exactly what you want to do and how.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my opinion, Xubuntu works nicely. It's attractive, light on resources, and still has the power to get things done. Also, lots of online support is available. I have used it with older computers and netbooks. Currently, I install Xubuntu to a USB flash drive via Unetbootin, creating a 1gb partition for the os and the rest to encrypted file storage, which makes a nice portable system that boots on most computers.

Puppy Linux is good, too, but takes some getting used to.